# Generic function conforming to custom protocol - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I want to make a function which accepts the desired return type as parameter and which should conform to my custom protocol.

Below is my code from playground.

```
protocol InitFunctionsAvailable {
    func custom(with: Array<Int>)
}

class model1: InitFunctionsAvailable {
    var array: Array<Int>!

    func custom(with: Array<Int>) {
        array = with
    }

}

func call<T: InitFunctionsAvailable>(someObject: T) -> T {

    return someObject.custom(with: []) as! T
}


let model = call(someObject: model1())

print(model.array)
```

**Im getting error**

> Could not cast value of type '()' (0x1167e36b0) to
>   '__lldb_expr_76.model1' (0x116262430).

What I need is the function should return the model depending on parameters.

Comment: `custom(with:)` returns `Void` (aka `()`).

Comment: @Cristik what should i change in my code

Comment: Not sure. Depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish; Are you trying to use `initFunctionsAvailable` to implement some sort of factory pattern?  What should `custom` return in your example? an instance of `model1`?

Comment: yes an instance of model1. it should vary according to my incoming parameter

Comment: You could change your protocol so that `custom` is declared as `func custom(with: Array<Int>) -> InitFunctionsAvailable`

Comment: yes its working. saved my life

Comment: **Unrelated**, don't just play around with `!` for optional types for the god sake.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
return someObject.custom(with: []) as! T
```

`someObject.custom(with: [])` has no return value, thus it "returns" `Void` (or `()` if you want), but you are trying to cast it to `T`, which in you example is `model1` instance. You cannot cast `Void` to `model1`.

You can in your case simplu fix it by changing `call` method from:

```
func call<T: InitFunctionsAvailable>(someObject: T) -> T {

    return someObject.custom(with: []) as! T
}
```

to:

```
func call<T: InitFunctionsAvailable>(someObject: T) -> T {
    // perform action on it
    someObject.custom(with: [])
    // and then return it
    return someObject
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That does the job too.

```
import Foundation

protocol InitFunctionsAvailable
{
    func custom(with: Array<Int>) -> InitFunctionsAvailable
}

class model1: InitFunctionsAvailable
{
    var array: Array<Int>!

    func custom(with: Array<Int>) -> InitFunctionsAvailable
    {
        array = with
        return self
    }
}

func call<T: InitFunctionsAvailable>(someObject: T) -> T
{
    return someObject.custom(with: []) as! T
}


let model = call(someObject: model1())

print(model.array)
```